# Cannot install Selenium chromedriver in a Docker Container

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using this Dockerfile to install Selenium chromedriver in a Docker container:

```
FROM python:3.8

# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

ENV DISPLAY=:99

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN chmod 755 ./run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/run.sh"]
```

I already used this Dockerfile some time ago and everything worked fine.
Now, I'm getting this error when I run:

```
docker build -t container .
```

The error while building:

```
[+] Building 2.8s (9/17)                                                                                                  
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 818B                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8                                                        2.1s
 => [ 1/13] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8@sha256:b9f9612dfd39f75b372056ebb50b9888b4ea7ba48e33d2342f7866816723fa  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 46.81kB                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/13] RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -            0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/13] RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/ap  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/13] RUN apt-get -y update                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [ 5/13] RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable                                                        0.7s
------                                                                                                                    
 > [ 5/13] RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable:                                                                   
#8 0.262 Reading package lists...                                                                                         
#8 0.536 Building dependency tree...
#8 0.599 Reading state information...
#8 0.650 E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable]: exit code: 100
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Which is the problem here?

Comment: Is it possible that the problem has to do with the fact that I am using in this case Docker Desktop, for a Mac with an Apple chip? https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/

Comment: yes, this is a problem with Mac (Apple Silicon)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an already existing image that does excatly that, as your starting point? For example, this looks like a functional docker image for chrome and python:

https://hub.docker.com/r/joyzoursky/python-chromedriver/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with Mac (Apple Silicon), it might work of others as well

In your Dockerfile use images by explicitly mentioning linux/amd6 using

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8
```

instead of

```
FROM python:3.8
```

OR

if you are using compose file, add platform to the image using

```
services:
  app:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ...
```